# C++ - Check if TCHAR array is empty

Tags: c++, arrays

I know this question may be a duplicate of some other ones, but I want to be sure I am correct before making this change so I am going to ask here anyway. In an old project I am maintaining  there is this line of code:

```
TCHAR m_sLogPath[MAX_LOGPATH_LEN];
```

There is line of code where the array is initialized and used but after a while there is this check:

```
if(NULL== m_sLogPath || _tcsicmp(m_sLogPath, trace_path)!=0){//code here}
```

I guess this if statement is checking to see if m_sLogPath is empty, but NULL== m_sLogPath is a pointless check as comparing an array to NULL doesnt make sense. Im going to have to remove the NULL== m_sLogPath peice, my question is what should go there instead to check the array is empty? Thanks for all answers and help,

Comment: When you say 'after a while' are you still dealing directly with the m_sLogPath or has it been passed as an argument at any point?

Comment: Maybe the person who wrote that is just paranoia about stack allocation :)

Comment: Just saying if that's a pointer to the original array (which it would be after being passed as an argument) then that is a very valid check.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out sji, its not passed as an argument at any point as far as I can see but its a very good point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right, that is a pointless check, if done in the same context.

If you pass it as parameter to a function, the the array decays into a pointer and it's not so pointless.

> what should go there instead to check the array is empty

Well, the array is never empty. It will always contain `MAX_LOGPATH_LEN` `TCHAR`s. But the following could do the trick:

```
if( m_sLogPath[0] == _T('\0') || _tcsicmp(m_sLogPath, trace_path)!=0)
```

Comment: Please use the _tcslen function. I know your code will work on all C compilers around the world, but one day, someone that doesn't know C will have to port that code.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you Luchian, I never knew that about passing it as a parameter to a function! Will mark as answer when I can!

Answer (score 3):

The `m_sLogPath` array always contains `MAX_LOGPATH_LEN` characters. Assuming that `MAX_LOGPATH_LEN` is a constant greater than 0, then the array will never really be empty.

I'm guessing that what you really want to check is whether the C-style string stored in this array is empty. If that's the case, then the simplest way to do it would be:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

const size_t MAX_LOGPATH_LEN = MAX_PATH;
TCHAR m_sLogPath[MAX_LOGPATH_LEN];

int main()
{
    if (m_sLogPath[0] == _T('\0'))
    {
        // m_sLogPath contains empty string.
    }
}
```